# curl#60 - "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate" with amzn2-core

Tags: curl, dockerfile, ssl-certificate, amazon-linux-2

I have a dockerfile that has the following snippet

```
FROM amazonlinux:2

USER root
WORKDIR /opt

# Install tools to allow for the creation of users
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install python3 \
    python3-pip \
    shadow-utils
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/yum
```

When the execution reaches the `RUN yum -y update` line, the docker build fail with the following message.

```
#8 [stage-1  3/12] RUN yum -y update
#8 sha256:61f006d09a5657d70db53766f2065fbdac47be5249a2a706558906ec28373b4f
#8 0.255 Loaded plugins: ovl, priorities
#8 4.352 https://cdn.amazonlinux.com/2/core/2.0/aarch64/b2a940e38a9dc9fb817c16cf37a42866e742622a57bb83c1794fe670037d513b/repodata/repomd.xml?instance_id=timeout&region=unknown: [Errno 14] curl#60 - "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"
#8 4.352 Trying other mirror.
#8 4.354 
#8 4.354 
#8 4.354  One of the configured repositories failed (Amazon Linux 2 core repository),
#8 4.354  and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
#8 4.354  safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:
#8 4.354 
#8 4.354      1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.
#8 4.354 
#8 4.354      2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
#8 4.354         upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
#8 4.354         distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
#8 4.354         packages for the previous distribution release still work).
#8 4.354 
#8 4.354      3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
#8 4.354             yum --disablerepo=amzn2-core ...
#8 4.354 
#8 4.354      4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
#8 4.354         will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
#8 4.354         again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:
#8 4.354 
#8 4.354             yum-config-manager --disable amzn2-core
#8 4.354         or
#8 4.354             subscription-manager repos --disable=amzn2-core
#8 4.354 
#8 4.354      5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
#8 4.354         Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
#8 4.354         so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
#8 4.354         slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
#8 4.354         compromise:
#8 4.354 
#8 4.354             yum-config-manager --save --setopt=amzn2-core.skip_if_unavailable=true
#8 4.354 
#8 4.354 failure: repodata/repomd.xml from amzn2-core: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
#8 4.354 https://cdn.amazonlinux.com/2/core/2.0/aarch64/b2a940e38a9dc9fb817c16cf37a42866e742622a57bb83c1794fe670037d513b/repodata/repomd.xml?instance_id=timeout&region=unknown: [Errno 14] curl#60 - "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"
#8 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yum -y update]: exit code: 1
------
 > [stage-1  3/12] RUN yum -y update:
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yum -y update]: exit code: 1
ERROR: Build failed with status '1'
```

All the suggested options in the error message failed. Any idea how can this be resolved?

There is internet connection as I can `curl www.google.com` however when use https it fails with — more or less— the same type of error.

```
#7 [stage-1  3/13] RUN curl https://www.google.com
#7 sha256:66e5bf50aa784be781fa4c6265b0653631376593efa8e69ecae189b4b3af3a44
#7 0.150   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
#7 0.150                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
#7 0.192 curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
#7 0.193 More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html
#7 0.193 
#7 0.193 curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
#7 0.193 establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
#7 0.193 how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
#7 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c curl https://www.google.com]: exit code: 60
------
 > [stage-1  3/13] RUN curl https://www.google.com:
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c curl https://www.google.com]: exit code: 60
ERROR: Build failed with status '1'
```

Comment: What is the output of: `curl -v -I https://www.google.com` ?   The link to https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html should have info to solve the problem.

Comment: Are you connected to the net through a business, organization, school, or other entity that might need to inspect traffic, or think it does? Do you have any security software, such as 'antivirus', on your computer that has SSL 'inspection' or 'monitoring' or 'protection' as a feature?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085  When I hit the URL directly from my machine I can download the file. So, I doubt it's because of VPN. Maybe my docker installation is not corrupted or I switched some overzealous security option.

Comment: Does 'directly'mean on the host and is the host Windows and do you use a non-Firefox browser or PS iwr (or dotnet) or ms-built curl? If so those all use the Windows cert store which is often set to accept interceptor certs even though they are not the the real ones. Look at the certs you are accepting, or receiving with `opensl s_client -showcerts` (or Java `keytool -princert -sslserver` if you have that!), and compare to the real ones shown by `www.ssllabs.com/ssltest`.